# Solving linear system with inequality constraints in Python or Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, linear-programming, linear-equation

I want to solve a linear system which is quite complicated, I take the following equations for an example:

```
(1) x + y = 0;
(2) x * y = -4;
(3) x > 0;
```

If only (1) and (2), there are two sets of solutions. So I add (3) to remove the ambiguity.

Solution in any programming language is Ok, better in Python or Matlab. Thanks very very much.

------*********---------

Equation (2) in my example is not linear, that's my mistake. I have solved my original complicated problem, which can be formulated by Ax=b where R(A)=R(b), the solution is unique, no need to add inequalities to remove ambiguity. Some unexpected artifacts made me think that there's ambiguity in the linear system, actually the ambiguity doesn't exist.
Finally I add more constraints into my linear system, and solve it with np.linalg.lstsq(), then the unexpected artifacts disappear.

Thank you all the guys, you do helped me a lot. It is not easy to describe the original problem, sorry for that.

Comment: Please add some details on what kinds of solvers you have experience with, and what prevents you attempting this problem yourself. Then answers can focus on teaching you that missing part. Otherwise you are asking for something vague and probably too much for a single Stack Overflow answer. Some code would be good . . . even if it only explains the question inputs, so far you don't even show whether your input is strings, or whether you want to solve a matrix/vector form?

Comment: Is your problem truly a linear system? Your `x * y` makes me doubt it. Otherwise, there are common solvers for linear systems of equations. Or are you interested in linear optimization (a.k.a. linear programming)?

Comment: (Large) systems of linear equalities and inequalities are easily solved with a Linear Programming solver. Just use a dummy objective (e.g. all cost coefficients equal to zero).

Answer (score 2):

There's **sympy**.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x y')
(x, y)
>>> solve([x+y,x*y+4])
[{x: -2, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: -2}]
>>> [(s[x],s[y]) for s in solve([x+y,x*y+4]) if s[x]>0]
[(2, -2)]
```

At its present state of development it does not solve systems involving inequalities and more than one variable. However, finding the desired solution in the results dictionary is easy.

Answer (score 0):

In `Matlab` this can be solved using the `Symbolic Toolbox` like this:

```
syms x y 

eq1= x+y==0
eq2= x*y==-4
eq3= x>0

s=solve([eq1 eq2 eq3],[x,y])

x_sol=s.x
y_sol=s.y
```

The result is:

```
x_sol =  2
y_sol = -2
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be done with scipy (python) if you want a numerical rather than symbolic solution. Instead of the third condition, you will have to give a starting point to remove the ambiguity:

```
    from scipy.optimize import fsolve

    def func(x):
        return np.array([x[0]+x[1],x[0]*x[1]+4]])

    x = fsolve(func, x0=[2,0])
```